# NameError: name "variable names" is not defined Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Select rows where both 'Rating' and 'Size' values are present (ie. the two values are not null)
apps_with_size_and_rating_present = apps[(~apps['Rating'].isnull()) & (~apps['Size'].isnull())]

# Subset for categories with at least 250 apps
large_categories = apps_with_size_and_rating_present.groupby(['Category']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 250)

# Plot size vs. rating
plt1 = sns.jointplot(x = large_categories['Size'], y = large_categories['Rating'])

# Select apps whose 'Type' is 'Paid'
paid_apps = apps_with_size_and_rating_present[apps_with_size_and_rating_present['Type'] == 'Paid']

# Plot price vs. rating
plt2 = sns.jointplot(x = paid_apps['Price'], y = paid_apps['Rating'])
```

Test cases are prompting errors.

> NameError: name 'apps_with_size_and_rating_present' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'large_categories' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'plt1' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'paid_apps' is not defined
>
> NameError: name 'plt2' is not defined

What's wrong in here?

Comment: From the Error statements, it's clear that those variable names are not defined before their call. You should Restart the Kernel and Re-Run it. Else than than you should also try to run them in separate cells. Make sure than previous cell is executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

```
# Select rows where both 'Rating' and 'Size' values are present (ie. the two values are not null)
apps_with_size_and_rating_present = apps[apps["Rating"].notnull() & apps["Size"].notnull()]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.